# Multi-platform OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, gradle

My goal is to build an Android application that will call some OpenCV code. In a first time, I will process everything from the android application, then, later on, I will move a part of the image processing on an external server. So I would like to differentiate the devellopment of the android application and the image processing logic.

What I have done so far is a project with the android application in Android Studio, and an other project with the Image processing techniques in IntelliJ with openCV windows libraries.

The only thing I managed to do to make things work in Android is copy/pasting my java files of the IntelliJ project into the Android Studio Project, but I would like a better way of integrating my code.

I tried three main different solutions as of now, and thought about a fourth one :

- Using jitpack, and it worked well. I don't know how it managed my IntelliJ code, but I was able to load the dependency from Android Studio and run it with the OpenCV android dependencies specified in Android Studio. The only problem is that Jitpack is not free and as I'm doing this on my personnal time and budget, I would like a free solution if that's possible.
- Build an android aar from IntelliJ switching OpenCV windows dependencies to OpenCV android dependencies with a -P in the gradle build command and some if/else in the `build.gradle`
- Reference my IntelliJ project from Android Studio app as a subproject and substitude dependencies
- Put a task of git clone in Android Studio build.gradle file and keep only cloned src files.

Both lead me to other problems that take so much time to resolve, so I'm questionning about the right way of doing this multi-platform process. Am I going the right way with one of the mentionned solutions ?